# how to change a map

Tags: navigation, mapping, sbpl, planner, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a question about how to change a map...I am new to ROS and Ubuntu 12.04 so I dont know really...

I am running SBPL Lattice planner and I want to compare that planner to the one i already have, so I should ride the robots on the same map. I need to change the map in SBPL Lattice planner to my map, so how can I do that?

And the other question would be, how can i type the coordinates where the Robot should go (there is 2D Nav Goal in rviz, but I need that the Robots go to the same place)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/164646/how-to-change-a-map/) by [Ico](https://answers.ros.org/users/17981/ico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-05-14

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Firstly, You have to include map of your environment in png format in your launch file. I assume that you are launching this file for SBPL planner :  launch / move_base_sbpl_fake_localization_2.5cm.launch

If you open this file, there is a node which include map and publishes map to the /map topic.

remove willlow.pgm and instead give your map address. also remove next  line its for inbuilt simulator stage.

so, Once try to run it on your robot and see the /map data on rviz,
( roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_navigation.launch ) is the best and simplest way to do it
Here you can give 2D navigation goal by manually clicking on the 2D map.

If you want to give goal position from terminal or code, you can modify the value of topic /move_base/simple_navigation_goal

(But, as you are trying to compare navigation i dont think that you would be bothered about exact same goal for both the planner. If you want exactly same goal then you should publish nav_goal to the above topic.)

NOTE: If you re-launch the map-server, it might not give same coordinate value for same point, i.e, ( point (0,0) might become point (2,2) in next iteration) So, consider that, For that i suggest you launch a separate file for /map and just relaunch the planners.

Hope this helped,
Sudeep

---

Originally posted by [Sudeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/9671/sudeep/) with karma: 460 on 2014-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To make robots go to the same place, both robots have to subscribe to this same topic

> /move_base/simple_navigation_goal

and process the goal for both robots to make them go to the same place.

---

Originally posted by [AbuIbra](https://answers.ros.org/users/6791/abuibra/) with karma: 118 on 2014-05-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1